# loadNiBName method executed twice

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

I xib customized by a bottom shell window, but when view controller inside call, `loadNibName` this method will always be executed twice. Xcode always pause here, but running on the phone, and there is no impact, I do not know why cause so curious.

Comment: Why would you concert about 'loadNibName'? You should worry only if your viewDidLoad is called twice on same object.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your code for Xcode to pause?

Comment: Because I'm using the View is drawn through xib, so I need to load it through loadNibName, but I found that this method will be executed twice. However, this issue does not affect the running program. I just want to know why executed twice.